# react-pdf library is giving error at gatsby build time

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, react-pdf

I am creating react product using gatsby. I am using react-pdf library. It is givining follwoing error at build time. How can I solve it?
I used gatsby 3.3.0 version.
and using react-pdf 5.2.0

```
D:\Project\public\render-page.js:137661
  window.requestAnimationFrame(resolve);

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at D:\Project\public\render-page.js:40343:3
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/lib/web/ui_utils.js (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:4034
2:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:48664:42)
    at Object../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/lib/web/pdf_link_service.js (D:\Brisktech\Android\public\render-page
.js:39345:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:48664:42)
    at Module../node_modules/react-pdf/dist/esm/LinkService.js (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:4
4080:93)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:48664:42)
    at Module../node_modules/react-pdf/dist/esm/Document.js (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:4351
2:71)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:48664:42)
    at Module../node_modules/react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack.js (D:\Brisktech\Android\public\render-page.js
:46550:67)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:48664:42)
    at Module../src/routes/default/index.js (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:7404:90)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:48664:42)
    at Object../.cache/_this_is_virtual_fs_path_/$virtual/sync-requires.js (D:\Brisktech\Android\public\rend
er-page.js:6740:116)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Project\public\render-page.js:48664:42)
D:\Project\public\render-page.js:40343
  window.requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
  ^
failed Building static HTML for pages - 2.931s

 ERROR #95313

Building static HTML failed

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  10 |
  11 | export default function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
> 12 |   if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
     | ^
  13 |   if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
  14 |   return Constructor;
  15 | }


  WebpackError: Call retries were exceeded

  - createClass.js:12
    [fitupme-app]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/esm/createClass.js:12:1



error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

If I lower the version of react-pdf then It is working but giving warning.
react-pdf: 4.2.0

```
 ERROR

(node:6076) [DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_CACHE] DeprecationWarning: Compilation.cache was removed in favor of
Compilation.getCache()
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)


 ERROR

(node:6076) [DEP_WEBPACK_TEMPLATE_PATH_PLUGIN_REPLACE_PATH_VARIABLES_HASH] DeprecationWarning: [hash] is now
[fullhash] (also consider using [chunkhash] or [contenthash], see documentation for details)


 ERROR

(node:6076) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEPRECATION_ARRAY_TO_SET_INDEXER] DeprecationWarning: chunk.files was changed from Array to Set (in
dexing Array is deprecated)
```

Can Anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error prompts in:

> See our docs page for more info on this error:
> https://gatsby.dev/debug-html

Your issue relies on the fact that `gatsby develop` occurs in the browser (where there are `window` and other global objects while `gatsby build` occurs in the Node server, where for obvious reasons there is no `window` (summarizing a lot).

When dealing with own code, you can bypass this issue wrapping your logic in the following condition:

```
import * as React from "react"

// Check if window is defined (so if in the browser or in node.js).
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"

export default function MyComponent() {
  let loggedIn = false
  if (isBrowser) {
    window.localstorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") === "true"
  }

  return <div>Am I logged in? {loggedIn}</div>
}
```

*Source: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/*

The snippet above will avoid a breaking build because it won't execute the offending part of the code thanks to `typeof window !== "undefined"` condition.

However, in your case, you are not dealing with own code so you need to tell webpack to avoid the transpilation of the offending modules. Add the following snippet in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /bad-module/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Basically, you are overwriting webpack's default configuration by telling it to ignore (or to add a `null` loader) to the `/bad-module/` dependency. As you can see, the test rule is a regular expression (that's why is wrapped between slashes) so you will need to change `/bad-module/` for the name of the dependency in `node_modules`. Something like this should work:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /react-pdf/, // check /pdfjs-dist/ too
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

`react-pdf` is trying to use `window` and/or `document`, what are undefined global objects at build-time to make their stuff so you are forced to pass a `null` loader to avoid the code-breaking. This is a "common" practice when dealing with third-party dependencies that use `window` in Gatsby.

Since it may not be exactly the third-party dependency that is causing the issue (it may be some dependency of `react-pdf`) you will need to make some trials testing dependencies based on the output log. Clean the cache in each trial using `gatsby clean` command.

Comment: Added given snippet, But it giving same error.

Comment: Look for the name of the library in `node_modules`, you may need to change it to `pdfjs-dist`. Clean the cache by `gatsby clean` in each trial

Comment: The solution is this one but you will need to find the offending module

Comment: Without seeing the warnings it's difficult... Warnings should be fixed but they won't break your code

Comment: Yes, Can you help me. Warnings are => warn WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage http.Agent
    at project/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node-http-handler/dist/es/node-http-handler
.js:19:1
    at projectp/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity/dist/es/runtimeConf
ig.js:20:153          ==> warn WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.readFileSync        ==> warn WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.readFileSync                        Can you help me?

Comment: Those are internal errors of `node_modules` dependencies, not from your code (aws). As soon as it doesn't break your code don't mind it.